# Python KIVY: how to dismiss 1 child button from a DropDown?

Tags: kivy

I would like to "hide" one child button from a dropdown, but I can't use dropdown.dismiss() because it hides every buttons. Here is a fake code that shows you what I want:

.kv:

:

```
Button:
    text: "Button 1"
    on_release: " hide button 2 "
Button:
    text: "Button 2"
    on_release: " no matter what "
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the button opacity by set it an id. Note that just hide the button, but don't remove the button from it root widget.

```
Button:
    text: "Button 1"
    on_release: bt2.opacity = 0
Button:
    id: bt2
    text: "Button 2"
    on_release: " no matter what "
```

Or even better if you want to hide and show the button:

```
on_release: bt2.opacity = int(not bt2.opacity)
```

Comment: Since DropDown is a subclass of GridLayout, you can just remove the button widget by adding this to a sibling button that will do the deleting:

`on_release: root.remove_widget(bt2)`

Comment: If the dropdown has 3 or more buttons or the OP want to hide the bt1 instead of the bt2 with your answer it will be a hole in the dropdown. the answer of @JohnAnderson is better but when you remove bt2 you must keep its value in order to add it again when needed